# using BigDecimal for very large numbers

Tags: java, algorithm

I have this code:

```
while (counter <= t)
{
   a = a * counter;
   c = c * r + a;
   counter++;
}
```

and I have `t` with the value `101835`.

The output should be 7.1*10^438, but NetBeans shows
the output as `infinity`.

Is there anything that will make the output as a decimal number?

Comment: what is value of `t` `a` `c`?

Comment: it is the time which is t=101835

Comment: Is BigDecimal class appropriate here ?

Comment: Let me guess, `a` and `c` are double and you wonder, why they can't hold such large numbers and show `infinity` instead? Is `BigDecimal` appropriate? You're exceeding the range of double, so what do you think?

Comment: c=0.0005, r=0.01, a=0.0006

Comment: yes I know, what should I do ?

Comment: Have you tried using `BigDecimal`? What are your results?

Comment: @shekharsuman This question has nothing to do with `netbeans`. OP might us it to program, but this question is unrelated to it. Or you can proof, that his problem can't be reproduced with other IDEs.

Comment: I agree @Tom, but, as op's title included it, so I edited the question with NetBeans tag.

Comment: @shekharsuman Then we should find a better title :).

Answer (score 1):

A [`double`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) as defined by IEEE-754 can't represent such a number, it's too large. The bounds are approximately between -10<sup>308</sup> and 10<sup>308</sup>.

You need to use a `BigDecimal` to represent it: a number with an arbitrary number of bytes to represent numbers.

Better way to implement this:

```
double c = 0.0005d;//initialize c
double r = 0.01d;  //initialize r
double a = 0.0006d;//initialize a
BigDecimal abd = new BigDecimal(a); //BigDecimal for a
BigDecimal cbd = new BigDecimal(c); //BigDecimal for c
BigDecimal rbd = new BigDecimal(r); //BigDecimal for r
for (int counter = 1; counter <= t; counter++) {//perhaps other offset for counter?
   abd = abd.multiply(new BigDecimal(counter));
   cbd = cbd.multiply(rbd).add(abd);
}
```

A potential problem with this approach is that the precision is too high: Java will calculate all operations exactly resulting in numbers that have thousands of digits. Since every operation blows up the number of digits, within a few iterations, simple addition and multiplication operations become unfeasible.

You can solve this by defining a precision using the optional `MathContext` parameter: it determines on how precise the result should be. You can for instance use `MathContext.DECIMAL128`:

```
int t = 101835;
double c = 0.0005d;//initialize c
double r = 0.01d;  //initialize r
double a = 0.0006d;//initialize a
BigDecimal abd = new BigDecimal(a); //BigDecimal for a
BigDecimal cbd = new BigDecimal(c); //BigDecimal for c
BigDecimal rbd = new BigDecimal(r); //BigDecimal for r
for (int counter = 1; counter <= t; counter++) {//perhaps other offset for counter?
    abd = abd.multiply(new BigDecimal(counter),MathContext.DECIMAL128);
    cbd = cbd.multiply(rbd,MathContext.DECIMAL128).add(abd,MathContext.DECIMAL128);
}
System.out.println(abd);
System.out.println(cbd);
```

This gives:

```
abd = 3.166049846031012773846494375835059E+465752
cbd = 3.166050156931013454758413539958330E+465752
```

This is approximately correct, after all the result of `a` should be:

[image]

Which is approximately correct according to *Wolfram Alpha*.

Furthermore I would advice to use a `for` and not a `while` if it is a `for` loop. Since `while` tends to create another type of infinity: an infinite loop ;).

Comment: It is better to use [`BigDecimal.valueOf(double)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#valueOf%28double%29) instead of `new BigDecimal(double)`.

Comment: @Tom: I'm not convinced. If one analyzes the Java Binary code, what it does is it calls `Double.toString()` and then parses it back. This is in my opinion a sign of *bad design* since the `toString` method can be culture dependent and many people don't think the way an object is textually represented has much impact on how it is handled. By first converting it to a `string` information may get lost and furthermore, these are expensive operations too.

Comment: No problem. If you prefer to ignore the inaccuracy of `double` instead. Btw. your BigDecimal `abd` is not `0.0006`, it is `0.000599999999999999947437878677902745039318688213825225830078125`

Comment: @Tom: well both methods are inaccurate. After all the value is first represented as a double anyway. The `valueOf` method sometimes benefits from the fact that a `Double.toString` rounds of to some significant digits. Thus *"repairing"* the number. But in the same number of cases, this can go badly wrong. If you would for instance enter `BigDecimal.valueOf(0.0123456789123456)`, the `new` approach is tiny bit more precise. The simple Engineering law is: *You can't do anything perfect.*. Your comment is valuable in the sense it provides a good alternative :).

Comment: `is tiny bit more precise`? If I print the value of that BigDecimal, then I'll get the exact value of `0.0123456789123456`.

Comment: This is a calculation to a bacteria culture left uncovered, so I am calculating the future concentration using 4 variables c which is the initial concentration, r which is the growth rate per second, a which is the bacteria coming to the culture from the environment and t which is the time elapsed in seconds. So I guess my calculation is the wrong thing here, anyone have suggestion to edit the code?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the only thing which you should use here is `BigDecimal` class. It'll easily handle that complex value without burdening you.

The maximum supported double value is only around `1.7 * 10^ 308` as given by `Double.MAX_VALUE` specified for Java.